# check uniqueness of multicolumn model in strongloop

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop, loopback

How can I validate multicolumn uniqueness in strongloop?

```
{
  "name": "Table1",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "column1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "column2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "column3": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {}
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

In above model, how can I make column1 and column2 as unique key in loopback model? I checked `validatesUniquenessOf` but it doesn't validate multiple columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is working with below:

```
Table1.validatesUniquenessOf('column1', 'column2');
```

Not sure, I tried it previously also but that time it was not working. Probably I didn't have re-started loopback server.